# OpenAI GPT-3 API error: "This model's maximum context length is 2049 tokens"

Tags: javascript, php, json, openai-api, gpt-3

I have two issues relating to the response result from OpenAI completion.

The following result doesn't return back the full text when I give a content of 500 words and prompt with "Fix grammar mistakes" **(Is tokens issue?)**

[image]

The second issue is when the text sometimes have some double quotes *or* single quotes. It messes with the JSON format. So I delete any type of quotes from the content (I am not sure if it's the best solution, but I may prefer doing it in JavaScript, not PHP).

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "{\n  \"model\": \"text-davinci-001\",\n  \"prompt\": \"" . $open_ai_prompt  . ":nn" . $content_text  . "\",\n  \"temperature\": 0,\n  \"top_p\": 1.0,\n  \"frequency_penalty\": 0.0,\n  \"presence_penalty\": 0.0\n}");
```

> "message": "We could not parse the JSON body of your request. (HINT:
> This likely means you aren't using your HTTP library correctly. The
> OpenAI API expects a JSON payload, but what was sent was not valid
> JSON.

Comment: `when the text sometimes have some double quotes OR single quotes it messes with the JSON format`...the solution to this kind of thing is: don't build your JSON by hand like that. Make a PHP object / array with the correct structure, and then use `json_encode()` to turn it into valid JSON, it will automatically handle any escaping etc which is needed, and you can also use the options to tweak certain things about the output - check the PHP documentation.

Comment: @ADyson Thanks I'll try encoding the whole payload how ever I did try encodeing then decoding the text before send it the API and it fails also with JS and PHP.

Comment: It's not clear precisely what you tried, from that description, but yes you need to JSON-encode the whole thing, from a PHP object, that will make it a lot more reliable in terms of creating valid JSON

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Regarding token limits

First of all, I think you don't understand how tokens work: **500 words is more than 500 tokens**. Use the [Tokenizer](https://platform.openai.com/tokenizer) to calculate the number of tokens.

As stated in the official [OpenAI article](https://help.openai.com/en/articles/4936856-what-are-tokens-and-how-to-count-them):

> Depending on the model used, requests can use up to `4097` tokens **shared**
> between prompt and completion. If your prompt is `4000` tokens, your
> completion can be `97` tokens at most.
>
> The limit is currently a technical limitation, but there are often
> creative ways to solve problems within the limit, e.g. condensing your
> prompt, breaking the text into smaller pieces, etc.

Switch `text-davinci-001` for a GPT-3 model because the token limits are higher.

[GPT-3 models](https://platform.openai.com/docs/models/gpt-3):

[image: Table]

#### Regarding double quotes in JSON

You can escape double quotes in JSON by using `\` in front of double quotes like this:

```
"This is how you can escape \"double quotes\" in JSON."
```

But... This is more of a quick fix. For proper solution, see @ADyson's comment above:

> Don't build your JSON by hand like that. Make a PHP object / array
> with the correct structure, and then use `json_encode()` to turn it into
> valid JSON, it will automatically handle any escaping etc which is
> needed, and you can also use the options to tweak certain things about
> the output - check the PHP documentation.

---

**EDIT 1**

You need to set the [`max_tokens`](https://platform.openai.com/docs/api-reference/completions/create#completions/create-max_tokens) parameter higher. Otherwise, the output will be shorter than your input. You will not get the whole fixed text back, but just a part of it.

---

**EDIT 2**

Now you set the `max_tokens` parameter too high! If you set `max_tokens = 5000`, this is too much even for the most capable GPT-3 model (i.e., `text-davinci-003`). The prompt and the completion **together** can be `4097` tokens.

You can figure this out if you take a look at the error you got:

```
"error": {"message": "This model's maximum context length is 4097 tokens, however you requested 6450 tokens (1450 in your prompt; 5000 for the completion). Please reduce your prompt; or completion length."}
```

Comment: I did try the highest model tokens and it success, the idea is even with the success the article is is about 700 word and when I use ```fix grammar mistakes``` for example, the result is not more than 70 word. Do you thing there's another better endpoint to use?

Comment: `You can escape double quotes in JSON by using \ in front of double quotes`...you can, but you shouldn't generate the JSON by hand to begin with - see my first comment on the main thread under the question.

Comment: @MostafaEzzat I edited my answer. You need to set the `max_tokens` parameter higher.

Comment: @ADyson You're right, will edit my answer. :)

Comment: "I think you don't understand how tokens work: 500 words is more than 500 tokens. Use Tokenizer to calculate the number of tokens." "You need to set the max_tokens parameter higher! Otherwise, output will be shorter than you input." – 
I did add max tokens field with 5000, so i tried to omit to figure out the result if it completes so with max_token: 5000 I get this 
```string(295) "{
  "error": {"message": "This model's maximum context length is 4097 tokens, however you requested 6450 tokens (1450 in your prompt; 5000 for the completion). Please reduce your prompt; or completion length.```

Comment: I got it sorry however the text is pretty short

Comment: It says 163 token on the [Tokenizer](https://platform.openai.com/tokenizer) but in the API result it's thousands, May I ask what's the best way to send the text in chunks?

Comment: I edited my answer once again. Just divide it into, let's say, 5 parts. Let me know if this solves your problem.

Comment: May I ask the last thing for the best way for sending the text in chunks to the API? is using spliting the text on each  3-4 new lines for example?

Comment: Hm, I'm not sure if splitting the text on each 3-4 lines will be the best option. Try to split the text on each 3-4 **sentences** instead. Make a test and see what works best.